# Pagination in Ruby when results fetched in a mySQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I fetch some rows in my Rails controller using the following query:

```
@main = connection.execute("SELECT code_ver, result FROM mastertest WHERE code_ver NOT LIKE '%DevBld%' AND date >= DATE_SUB( (CURDATE()) , INTERVAL 90 DAY) ORDER BY date DESC;")
```

Now in my index.html.erb (View) I display these rows in form of a table.

But I want to have next and previous buttons in my html page such that It should display only a few rows at a time. Lets assume a week's data at a time.

Comment: You mean "Rails controller"? I suppose this is a rails app, judging from your tags? If yes, what version exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pagination, I'd go with [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

To fetch the 7th page of users, 20 per page:

```
User.page(7).per(20)
```

Better yet, to get nice `First Prev 2 3 [4] 5 6 ... Next Last` links in your views, all you need is:

```
<%= paginate @users %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the will_paginate gem that I learned about in the [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). It works wonderfully.

Comment: Can you construct a mySQL query that I can use with will_paginate for the above query given ?